# ¿Cómo puedo saber si un parámetro de URL existe o no en mod-rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Tengo una url:

https://example.com

Y lo que necesito es que si determinado parámetro de URL no existe (llámese `parameter`), te redirija a la misma URL pero con ese parámetro:

https://example.com/?parameter=value

Lo intenté como pude con `mod_rewrite` pero no pude.

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo hacer eso?
Gracias de antemano y espero que me puedas ayudar. Ten un lindo día. :D

Comment: agrega los "como pude" y vemos que le falta

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esto es lo que buscas:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(.*&)?parameter=(.*)? [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) $1?parameter= [R=302,QSA]
```

No requiere mucha explicación. En el `RewriteCond` comprobamos que la `QUERY_STRING` comience con `parameter=` o con cualquier cadena (opcionalmente) que acabe en `&`. También comprobamos que después del `=` continúe (opcionalmente). Luego *negamos* la expresión regular con `!` al principio para que sea verdadera cuando no se encuentre el parámetro. Entonces:

- `index.html?parameter=&a=1`: Falso
- `index.html?a=1&parameter=`: Falso
- `index.html?the-parameter=`: Verdadero

A continuación la `RewriteRule` redirecciona todas las peticiones cumplan la condición anterior a la misma url con los parámetros actuales (esto es por el `QSA`) y añadiendo `parameter=`.